# Question on the Bayesian equation for $ p(w|y,x)$

Tags: bayesian

I'm new to this topic.

Suppose that

- $ f(x) = x^Tw$, where both $x$ and $w$ are independent random variables with known probability density function.
- $ y(x) = f(x) + \epsilon $ where  $ \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2_n)$, and $\epsilon$ is independent of $x$ and $w$.

I would like to show that
$$ p(w|y,x) = \frac{p(y|x,w) p(w)}{p(y|x)}. $$

Here is what I have tried:

[image: problem equation]

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks !! @shaun

Comment: I dont see the question. what do you want to prove

Comment: Hi @user144410 can't you see the attached picture?

Comment: I can see it, but there is not enough information. What are the assumptions on x, y, and w. Is w independent of x for example?

Comment: maybe yes... w is independent of x  and $ w \sim N(0,\sum_p)$

Comment: maybe yes... w is independent of x  and $ w \sim N(0,\sum_p)$
Like the picture, i try to prove the equation using bayesian equation. However I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$p(x,y,w) = p(w | x ,y) p(x,y)  = p(w | x ,y) p(y|x) p(x) $$
and because $w$ and $x$ are independent $p(w|x) = p(w)$, and it holds that 
$$ p(x,y,w) = p(y | x ,w) p(w|x) p(x)   = p(y | x ,w) p(w) p(x) $$

Therefore, equating the right hand sides, you get the desired expression.

Comment: Thank you very much.. 
The important thing is whether w is independent of x or not. So, I have searched the relation between x and w. please check the main contents.

Comment: Hi @user144410, I completely understand it.!!!  

You're right. **$x$ is independent of $w$ even though $w$ and $x$ are dependent on $y$ because of $y = x^Tw + \epsilon$**

Comment: @Trainer99 You are welcome
!